# Computing the input voltage that turns the LED on

Tags: led, bjt, npn

We assume that the LED will light as soon as the transistor comes out of the cut-oﬀ region, therefore the BJT is on and operates in the active region. I know that that Vbe = 0.7V, Ib>0, ic=BIb and Vce>=0.7. Is this inequality for Vi expected for the BJT in the active region? If so, what value should we expect fot saturation mode?

[image: NPN BJT circuit]

[image: Calculations]

Comment: It is important to remember hFE drops to 10% of the max value when fully saturated or =10 typ. at rated value of Vce=Vce(sat)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are very close. You unfortunately dropped the minus sign on your third last line. After correcting that, you will find Vi <= 1.66 V